# Switching to a view made in interface builder from code

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I've created an app with a navigation bar and a table view. When I press a entry in the table, I want it it take me to a new view to display some information on it. I've gotten it so that I can press a cell and call a function into the code. What I need to do in the other view is very simple, so I made it in interface builder, and I'd like to keep it that way. Is there any way that I can change to the view with the push animation to retain the navigation bar thing from the code, but while the view is made in interface builder? Thanks.

PS I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am making this in iOS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In interface builder, in your first view controller (containing table view), define a manual Segue, with identifier set as 'ToDetailView'.

Then in:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToDetailView" sender:self];
}
```

Additionally you can implement following to pass any need data to second view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ToDetailView"])
    {


    }
}
```